# How to get number of locations of a Kindle ebook programatically?

Tags: kindle, mobi

I've been googling around for some time but couldn't find absolutely any clue. I have an ebook file in mobi format and would like get the number of locations of this ebook. I want to do it programatically so I could open a bunch of files and get that information in a second.

I was looking for some information about mobi file format, opened the file in a hex editor but I can't see anything useful. Has anyone done that?

Comment: I haven't tested anything myself, but this discussion might be helpful: https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=159357

Comment: WHat is "the number of locations of this ebook" the number of placenames it mentions?

Comment: No, it's an equivalent of number of pages of a traditional, paper book. It can be displayed at the bottom of a screen.

Answer (score 0):

Number of locations isn't in the metadata of a book file, it's the Kindle's calculation based off the book length. That thread mentioned give's some guesses about what the calculation is, but they still appear to be guesses. Theoretically, if you know the formula you can just create a simple program in Excel, enter the variables for each book, and get your answers.